# Reveal more text on click for multiple "show more" buttons. Duplicate didn't work

Tags: javascript, velo

This opens more text when I click a button. Now I need more of these on a web page. I duplicated the function and renamed in const lines the names to `menubutton2` and `dropdownmenu3` but the second button doesn't work

```js
import wixAnimations from 'wix-animations';

$w.onReady(function() {
  activeMenu();
});

function activeMenu() {
  const menuButton = $w('#menuButton');
  const dropdwonMenu = $w('#dropdownMenu');
  const dropdownBoxHeight = 0;
  const dropdownAnimation =
    wixAnimations.timeline().add(dropdwonMenu, {
      y: 0,
      duration: 100
    });

  wixAnimations.timeline().add(dropdwonMenu, {
    y: -
      dropdownBoxHeight
  }).play();

  menuButton.onClick(() => {
    dropdwonMenu.collapsed ? openMenu() : closeMenu();
  });

  dropdownAnimation.onReverseComplete(() => {
    dropdwonMenu.collapse();
  });

  function openMenu() {
    dropdwonMenu.expand().then(() => {
      dropdownAnimation.play();
    })
  }

  function closeMenu() {
    dropdownAnimation.reverse();
  }
}

import wixAnimations from 'wix-animations';
$w.onReady(function() {
  activeMenu();
});

function activeMenu() {
  const menuButton = $w('#menuButton2');
  const dropdwonMenu = $w('#dropdownMenu2');
  const dropdownBoxHeight = 0;
  const dropdownAnimation =
    wixAnimations.timeline().add(dropdwonMenu, {
      y: 0,
      duration: 100
    });

  wixAnimations.timeline().add(dropdwonMenu, {
    y: -
      dropdownBoxHeight
  }).play();

  menuButton.onClick(() => {
    dropdwonMenu.collapsed ? openMenu() : closeMenu();
  });

  dropdownAnimation.onReverseComplete(() => {
    dropdwonMenu.collapse();
  });

  function openMenu() {
    dropdwonMenu.expand().then(() => {
      dropdownAnimation.play();
    })
  }

  function closeMenu() {
    dropdownAnimation.reverse();
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you'd show exactly what you've tried so far, you could get a pointer or two at what you did wrong.

Comment: I tagged Velo, since that seems to be the framework you are using. I did not manage to make a [mcve]

Comment: You don't have `dropdownmenu3` in your code.